# GAE NDB Accessing sub-instances (fields) within structured repeated list

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am having difficulties with accessing an instance within a structured list.
Below is my structured list:

```
class FavFruits(ndb.Model):
    fruit    = ndb.StringProperty()
    score    = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    comment  = ndb.TextProperty()

class UserProfile(ndb.Model):
    uid            = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    password       = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    firstName      = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    favFruits      = ndb.StructuredProperty(FavFruits, repeated=True)
```

I want to display `score` under `FavFruits` entity.

I tried `UserProfile.favFruits.score` with no luck.

I also tried `UserProfile.favFruits[index].score`, which worked, but now requires looping and I would like to avoid it.

Ultimately, I want to do the following logic:

1. if UserProfile.uid == userEntering then user enters fruit name
2. if UserProfile.favFruits.fruit == fruitName (user entered) then display UserProfile.favFruits.score and UserProfile.favFruits.comments for UserProfile.favFruits.fruit specified by user.
3. Lastly, I would like to display all the fruit/scores that user enters.  Say, user entered "apple" and "orange" for fruit names, then I want to loop, for example (along this line):

`for x in fruitNames
 print x
 print UserProfile.favFruits.score.query(UserProfile.favFruits.fruit == x)`

Is this possible?  Seemingly trivial task, but I cannot figure this out..

Thank you in advance!

Comment: As Daniel said, you have to loop.

Comment: @TimHoffman Thank you. I will try playing around with looping.  So far, I can do this `for x in UserProfile.favFruits` then `print x.fruit == 'apple'` and seems like this is working.  Does this look okay?  Or is there a better method?  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your requirements are contradictory. If you don't want to loop, then don't use `repeated=True`. But then you won't be able to store more than one for each entity. There's no possible way to have multiple things without looping or indexing.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. If possible, can you provide your suggested method?  If I do not use `repeated=True`, then can I still choose, say, "apple" and remove associated content and score?  I currently do this by `pop()` on the list by index.  If it is best to keep `repeated=True`, how should I architecture the loop?  I want to do something like `for x in UserProfile.favFruits.fruit` but this would not work unless I provide the index.  NDB and structured list is totally new to me, hence these questions.  Thank you very much.